# Using view method inside ViewModel (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel

Let's say I am using the FlowDocumentPageViewer and I want to use the find method. 
How do I use it while following the rules of MVVM? I've done a few searches and it seems like the solutions are mixed.

Some suggest that you aggregate the View to the ViewModel and then use it to call the method that is needed:

Ex:

```
private MainWindow mw; 

public MainWindowViewModel(MainWindow mw)
{
    this.mw = mw;
}

public void Find()
{
    mw.flowDocument.find();
}
```

but others suggest that it's ok to use these methods in the view (Code-Behind) because the ViewModel shouldn't be calling View specific methods.

Lastly I've heard of solving this issue using Attached Behaviours but I haven't looked that up extensively to see if that method is suitable or not.

I really don't know which method is correct or if all of these methods are incorrect on how to handle this situation. If you can give me some insight on which method is preferred and why, I would be truly grateful.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Well, to really help you out here: how do you intend to invoke the method? Is it tied to a button? Then use a command. Is it automatic based on a PropertyChanged event? Then just call it in the ViewModel from the property. More information about the total solution if you would.

Comment: @Xcalibur37 No it's not tied to a button. It's a method tied to the view called find. It's a part of FlowDocumentPageViewer.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310867/mvvm-how-to-call-method-on-view-from-view-model/25310971

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would solve this problem with something like **MVVMLight messaging**. (From the Viewmodel you send a message and on the View's Code behind you register for this message.)

Jesse Liberty of Microsoft has [a great tutorial](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/01/06/windows-phone-from-scratch%E2%80%93mvvm-light-toolkit-soup-to-nuts-3/) on how to make use of the messaging within MVVM Light.

A class which act as your message type:

```
public class FlowDocumentFindMessage
{
   public string PageName { get; private set; }
   // or some other properties go here

   FlowDocumentFindMessage(string pageName){
          this.PageName = pageName
   }
}
```

The new Find, which sends a message

```
public void Find()
{
    var msg = new FlowDocumentFindMessage("Page");
    Messenger.Default.Send<FlowDocumentFindMessage>( msg );
}
```

Code Behind, which registers for new message

```
Messenger.Default.Register<GoToPageMessage>( this, ( action ) => ReceiveMessage( action ));

private object ReceiveMessage( FlowDocumentFindMessage action )
{
    //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: This is a good decoupling of View and ViewModel. A few things to note though:
1. double check not to send messages before view has registered, if your logic depends on it, you might run into an unpredicted state
2. double check whether your control supports message handler logic before control IsLoaded, you might get exceptions if called to early
Consider these if you're sending messages in Loaded events or ViewModel creation scenarios, otherwise your good to go.